# after dismissing viewController, popViewController won't work

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have stucked in scenario:
look at this picture:
[image]

I have soundPlayerVC as childeViewController of pageContentVC.

soundPlayerVC Present mail modalViewController:

```
- (IBAction)emailStory:(id)sender {

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    Anecdote *anecdote = (Anecdote *)story;
    [picker setSubject:anecdote.name];
    [picker setMessageBody:[SearchHandler removeMarkupsFromPageText:anecdote.detail] isHTML:NO];
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

    #pragma mark - mail compose delegates
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but when I tap on backButton, popViewController doesn't work, because navigationController has been emptied!!

HOW THIS HAPPENED? 
could someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
that was because of I didn't popViewController in the right viewController.

`pageContentVC` is child of `bookRootVC` so `bookRootVC` is responsible of removing `pageContnetVC` from navigationController Stack.

I created a protocol and added a delegate property `pageContnetVC` and assigned `bookRootVC` as delegate of `pageContnetVC`

```
protocol DismissViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)popViewController;
@end
```

`bookRootVC` implement the protocol:

```
#pragma mark pop view controller delegate
- (void)popViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
```

and finally backButton in `pageContentVC` call its delegate to remove this view from navigationController.

thats all!